# QML RowLayout does not dynamically resize based on content

Tags: qt, layout, qml

I have some experience with Qt Widgets, but only recently started to use QML.

The problem I face is that I'd like some layouts defined in QML to automatically adjust to fit their contents. This works, but not dynamically, i.e. if the content changes the layout does not adapt. With the old-style (non-QML) Layout/Widget approach, this happened automatically.

Here is an example (my code looks different and consists of different files, but I pasted this MWE together to demonstrate the problem):

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    property var nbx: 3

    Column {
        RowLayout {
            Repeater {
                model: 3
                Rectangle {
                    width:  childrenRect.width     
                    height: childrenRect.height
                    color: "green"
                    ColumnLayout {
                        Rectangle {
                            height: 10
                        }
                        RowLayout {
                            Repeater {
                                model: root.nbx
                                Rectangle {
                                    width:  20
                                    height: 20
                                    color: "orange"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Button {
            text: "5 boxes"
            onClicked: root.nbx= 5;
        }
        Button {
            text: "2 boxes"
            onClicked: root.nbx = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the same with QML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it work by setting the *implicit* size of the green `Rectangle` to the *implicit* size of the child `ColumnLayout`. I'm not exactly sure why, it seems the `childrenRect` properties are not propertly updated.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    property var nbx: 3

    ColumnLayout {
        RowLayout {

            Repeater {
                model: 3

                Rectangle {
                    implicitHeight: col1.implicitHeight   // <--- here is the change
                    implicitWidth: col1.implicitWidth
                    color: "green"

                    ColumnLayout {
                        id: col1

                        Rectangle {
                            height: 10
                        }
                        RowLayout {
                            Repeater {
                                model: root.nbx
                                Rectangle {
                                    width:  20
                                    height: 20
                                    color: "orange"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Button {
            text: "5 boxes"
            onClicked: root.nbx= 5;
        }
        Button {
            text: "2 boxes"
            onClicked: root.nbx = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Two questions though: 1) is the implicit size always the real size? 2) how could I achieve the behaviour of a QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding in the QWidget world. In other words, have my boxes fill the entire width of the window, regardless of the window size?

Comment: `childrenRect` works fine - `implicitWidth: childrenRect.width` would also do the job.

Comment: It's just Layouts do not respond to `width/height` property changes, but they do when `implicitWidth/implicitHeight` changes. QML Layouts have their quirks.

Comment: @user52366 You use `Layout.fillWidth` attached property.

Comment: @user52366 implicit size is supposed to be a "natural" size of an item. In a context of layouts it is supposed to be an "ideal" size of an item. It was added to break cyclic dependencies when calculating component sizes, i.e. when you want to set the size of a parent item based on its contents, which otherwise would affect the size of the children themselves.

Comment: @user52366 in other words implicit size should never affect children, whereas `width` and `height` often does.

Comment: @user52366 Do you understand why Layouts do not respond to `width/height` property changes?

Comment: @doc I understand the idea. But in the example, if I wanted the boxes to scale to the width of the containing window, then the effective size I'd get would not be `implicitWidth` but some larger `width`, right? I tried to set only `implicitWidth`, and added `layout.fillWidth: true` to all the layouts, but the boxes do not expand to a total width of 640px.

Comment: @user52366 You have to decide if you build layout from the bottom (by setting a width of deepest item and then asking layout to just position them) or you buld layout from the top and you ask layout to also calculate sizes. [Here's](https://pastebin.pl/view/96cc2773) simplified example of what you are asking. Try to add elements one by one, rather than creating lots of nested items at once. Remember that with QML you can easily group pieces of code and isolate it within separate components, so you won't end up with huge files of nested items, where it can be really hard to see what's going on.

Comment: @user52366 BTW have you read [Quick poistioning manual](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-topic.html)?

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I think the problem I have is that I am trying to translate the approach I'd have taken with C++/QWidget to QML. There I can control the geometry both from the top and from the bottom, by having a minimum size and the corresponding QSizePolicy (QMinimumExpanding) that enforces a minimum size yet fills the space if there is more available.

Comment: Maybe I can achieve this with layout.minimumWidth, need to try...

Comment: @user52366 yes you can. What I meant is that you can't do both at the same time, like in your example, where you explicitly set the size of Rectangle instead of relying on layout.